# How to get the predict probability?

Tags: pytorch

This code get the `1` or `0` value from model. 
If I want to get the probability of the prediction 
Which line should I change?

```
from torch.autograd import Variable
results = []
#names = []
with torch.no_grad():
    model.eval()
    print('===============================================start')
    for num, data in enumerate(test_loader):
        #print(num)
        print("=====================================================")

        imgs, label = data
        imgs,labels = imgs.to(device), label.to(device)
        test = Variable(imgs)
        output = model(test)
        #print(output)
        ps = torch.exp(output)
        print(ps)
        top_p, top_class = ps.topk(1, dim = 1)
        results += top_class.cpu().numpy().tolist()



model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
model.fc = nn.Linear(2048, num_classes)
model.cuda()
```

Comment: From `top_p, top_class = ps.topk(1, dim = 1)` print `top_p` it must contain probability

Comment: top_p looks like tensor([[ 15.0558],
        [225.5229],
        [204.3323],
        [124.6181],
        [212.8658],
        [239.8973],
        [188.1104],
        [ 13.3096],
        [146.6426],
        [ 12.6521],
        [232.5268],
        [ 73.8362],
        [209.5141],
        [307.2397],
        [219.1580],
        [130.2537]

Comment: It will required more information. Add `model` your network architecture in question. Then someone will able to help.

Comment: Why do you `torch.exp` your `output`s?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Models usually outputs raw prediction logits. To convert them to probability you should use [`softmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#softmax) function

```py
import torch.nn.functional as nnf

# ...
prob = nnf.softmax(output, dim=1)

top_p, top_class = prob.topk(1, dim = 1)
```

new variable `top_p` should give you the probability of the top k classes.